cv.calcHist()'s answer is different from np.histogram(), why?
I find the results are different between cv.calcHist() and np.histogram(), when leaning image histogram. I calculate the sum of image's pixels, cv's reusult and np's result separately. The results are 699392(pixels), 699392.0(cv) and 2098176(np). Why is np's result different?
I also find the max and min are different.
cv:

np:

This is my codes:
img = cv.imread("Unequalized.jpg") # grayscale image

hist_cv = cv.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
hist_np, _ = np.histogram(img.ravel(), 256, [0, 256])

print(img.shape[0] * img.shape[1]) # 699392
print(np.sum(hist_cv))             # 699392.0
print(np.sum(hist_np))             # 2098176

I have checked syntax, and I think it's correct. I'm excepting that np's result should be same as cv's.

2098176 / 699392 == 3

# grayscale image -- that's a lie, since you left the flags parameter at its default of cv.IMREAD_COLOR.

it might have been grayscale but imread() by default always returns BGR, so it'd convert a grayscale image. IMREAD_UNCHANGED to get the depth and number of channels that are actually in the image. or IMREAD_GRAYSCALE to convert if needed
